# Buscar y reemplazar strings con sufijos y prefijos en linux

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

Tengo en un fichero de salida los numeros de linea de un fichero inicial al que quiero hacer unas modificaciones y en el fichero en cuestion lo tengo asi guardado

1
30
35
90
...

Lo que me gustaria hacer es modificarlo para que me muestre lo siguiente:

`sed -i '` (como prefijo)

`Los numeros de linea como parte de entrada.`

`s///g'` fichero_a_modificar como prefijo.

Para que quede de esta manera:

`sed -i '1s///g' fichero_a_modificar`

`sed -i '30s///g' fichero_a_modificar`

Sabeis como podria hacerlo en linux.

Answer (score 0):

Fichero `reemplazar.sh`:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

declare -r reemplazar_in="$1"
declare -r fichero_a_modificar="$2"
declare -r from="${3//\//\\/}"
declare -r to="${4//\//\\/}"

while read -r; do
    printf "sed -i '%ss/%s/%s/g' '%s'\n" "${REPLY}" "${from}" "${to}" "${fichero_a_modificar}"
done < <(tr " " "\n" < "${reemplazar_in}")
```

Fichero ejecutable con este comando:

```bash
chmod +x reemplazar.sh
```

Y usado así:

```bash
./reemplazar.sh reemplazar-in.txt fichero_a_modificar from_txt to_txt
```

Con este archivo como entrada (`reemplazar-in.txt`):

```
1 30 35 90
```

El resultado es:

```bash
sed -i '1s/from_txt/to_txt/g' 'fichero_a_modificar'
sed -i '30s/from_txt/to_txt/g' 'fichero_a_modificar'
sed -i '35s/from_txt/to_txt/g' 'fichero_a_modificar'
sed -i '90s/from_txt/to_txt/g' 'fichero_a_modificar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo fácilmente con Perl, que viene con cualquier distribución Linux.

Suponiendo que tengas los números en un fichero "numeros" con este contenido:

```
1 30 35 90
```

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
perl -aE $'say "sed -i \'${_}s///g\' fichero_a_modificar" for @F' numeros
```

Que te daría como resultado:

```
sed -i '1s///g' fichero_a_modificar
sed -i '30s///g' fichero_a_modificar
sed -i '35s///g' fichero_a_modificar
sed -i '90s///g' fichero_a_modificar
```

El script explicado:

La opción `a`en Perl hace que se guarde en el array @F el contenido del fichero (se separa por espacios)

Después se recorre el array con un bucle y se va imprimiendo cada línea con `say`. En cada iteración, cada número viene guardado en la "variable por defecto" (`$_`)